# Form data into database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I've created a HTML form that inserts user data into a database using MySQL and PHP.

HTML form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" >

    <div class="container">

        <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" id="username" name="username" required>

        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="psw" name="psw" required>

        <label for="email"><b>Email address</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" id="email" name="email" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">

    </div>
</form>
```

index.php:

```
// Create connection
   $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_error());

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $USER = (isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null);
    $PASSWORD = (isset($_POST['psw']) ? $_POST['psw'] : null);
    $EMAIL = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO webapp_db.users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $USER, $PASSWORD, $EMAIL);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully";
} else{
    die('Error: '.mysqli_error($dbc));
}
$stmt->close();
$dbc->close();
```

And I don't get any errors. It says: "New records created successfully" but nothing has been created

Any idea where the problem is? Thank you in advance

Comment: Now that you have edited your code you should edit the error message(s) you are getting. You're not going to get the undefined index errors now they are wrapped in `isset` checks.

Comment: @Andy just did!

Comment: Cool. I also see a couple other issues which may just be copy/paste issues. `$_post['Submit']` should be `$_POST['Submit']`, and `USER = ` should be `$USER = `

Comment: Exactly, copy/paste issues :D

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the checks into isset() statements like so:

```
// Create connection
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_error());

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    $USER = (isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null);
    $PASSWORD = (isset($_POST['psw']) ? $_POST['psw'] : null);
    $EMAIL = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);

    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO webapp_db.users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $USER, $PASSWORD, $EMAIL);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully";
} else{
    die('Error: '.mysqli_error($dbc));
}
$stmt->close();
$dbc->close();
```

Comment: I would move the issets under the `if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {`

Comment: I have already tried that. Now it doesn't print any errors and it still doesn't insert the data into the database.

Comment: `if(isset($_post['Submit'])) {` the variable needs to be uppercase `if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {`

Comment: If you see nothing it means the script is probably erroring, have you checked the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, remember that [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) function returns a boolean. Try to check if the query were executed with success or not:

```
$executed = $stmt->execute();

if ($executed == true) { // or just "if ($executed) {" if you prefer
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Oops! Something went wrong";
}
```

But if you need something more precise, ... try with [errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) function, that returns an array.

```
if ($executed == 1) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: I tried that. This is the error that I am getting: 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [errno] => 1048 [sqlstate] => 23000 [error] => Column 'username' cannot be null ) [1] => Array ( [errno] => 1048 [sqlstate] => 23000 [error] => Column 'username' cannot be null ) )

Comment: try bindParam instead of bind_param

Comment: Error now: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam()

Comment: No sorry, a was wondering in pdo extension instead of mysqli: bind_param is correct

Comment: Sorry, ... what does $USER contains?

Comment: Well, I think you have submitted the form without a username ^_^

Comment: $user contains the username, and I cannot submit the form without a username because it's a required filed. The problem is that it doesn't read it...

Comment: Please, var_dump($USER) before bind_param. What $USER variable contains?

Comment: NULL -- USER contains:         $USER = (isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null);

Comment: ok, ... now try with `if (isset($_POST['username'])) { var_dump($_POST); }` at the beginning of the if statement.

Comment: Now nothing happens

Comment: Nice, ... add `die;` statement after `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Still, nothing happens :/

Comment: Add an `echo 'foo';` before and after the `var_dump`. Nothing?

Comment: Also, ... try to add a `var_dump($_POST);` before the `if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {` statement.

Comment: This is what it get: array(0) { }

Comment: Wait, ... if $POST is an empty array, ... is not possible that isset($_POST['Submit']) returns true, ...

Comment: $_POST['Submit'] doesn't return true, it directly doesn't execute the code inside the if statement